# React-native modal component not rolling back when child compoent involves

Tags: javascript, react-native, components

When I press on the submit button, the modal slides up but when I press on the "Hide Modal" it doesn't roll back to its origin. I console log the ChildScreen.js file after the onPress callback and I get:

Object {
  "modalVisible": false,
}

which means that the modal has to rollback to its original position, but this doesn't happend! Does any one know why? Note: the modal perfectly works when I don't import the  !

ParentScreen.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Modal } from "react-native";
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import ChildScreen from './ChildScreen';

export default class ParentScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    modalVisible: false
  }

  setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({ modalVisible: visible });
  }
  _onPress() {
    this.setModalVisible(true);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Modal
          animationType={"slide"}
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => { alert("Modal has been closed.") }}
        >
          <View style={{ marginTop: 22 }}>
            <ChildScreen />
          </View>
        </Modal>
        <View
          style={{
            position: 'absolute', bottom: 30, left: 0, right: 0, justifyContent: 'center',
          }}
        >
          <Button
            onPress={this._onPress.bind(this)}
            title='SUBMIT' />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

ChildScreen.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';


class ChildScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    modalVisible: true
  }

  setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({ modalVisible: visible });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>ChildScreen</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
          this.setModalVisible(this.state.modalVisible = false)
          console.log(this.state)
        }}>
          <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default ChildScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a callback called **hide** to the `<ChildScreen />` component like:

```
<ChildScreen
   hide={this.onModalChange}
/>
```

and called it like:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.hide}>
   <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

I changed my state management to **redux** and everything works perfectly.